# Why does this SQL INSERT using a loop break on certain characters?

Tags: sql, oracle, bash, csv

I am using a loop within a script to INSERT a row in to a database, but when a customer name contains certain characters it breaks.

**Data**

```
'1' 'Some+Customer Limited' 'email@somecustomerlimited.com'
```

**Expecting**

```
$a = '1'
$b = 'Some+Customer Limited'
$c = 'email@somecustomerlimited.com'

INSERT INTO t1 (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6) VALUES ($a, 1, $c, $c, 0, 0);
```

**Error**

```
INSERT INTO t1 (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6) VALUES ('1', 1, 'Some+Customer, Limited' 'email@domain.com', 0, 0)
                                                                                                                                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00917: missing comma
```

There is no missing comma in the script as you can see above i.e. `VALUES ($a, 1, $c, $c, 0, 0);`. Is this because of the space in the customer name, or the `+` in the customer name?

Comment: "C" in CSV stands for "comma". Your "CSV" does not have a single comma in it.

Comment: No it is because of the missing comma between ...Limited' and 'email@...

Comment: @MartinK. In the script see this comma is present (`VALUES ($a, 1, $b, $c, 0, 0);`), just not when the script is working, hence the question.

Comment: I see SQL Injection hole here

Comment: What does this have to do with `bash` or `csv`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the problem is that `read` splits on spaces (actually any character contained in $IFS), without caring of the quotes.

so instead of :

```
$a = '1'
$b = 'Some+Customer Limited'
$c = 'email@somecustomerlimited.com'
```

you have :

```
$a = "'1'"
$b = "'Some+Customer"
$c = "Limited' 'email@somecustomerlimited.com'"
```

as far as I know there is no way to make `read` 'quote aware' or split on regex, you have to choose a special character to delimit the fields of the CSV

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what would the simplest solution be? At the moment the data is like `'1' 'Some+Customer Limited 'email@somecustomerlimited.com'`, should I change the data to another format?

Comment: This is more a workaround than a robust solution but if you are sure that the data doesn't contains some character, say '|', you can use it as delimiter
e.g. 1|'Some+Customer Limited'|'email@somecustomerlimited.com'
then set it to IFS :
export IFS="|"

Answer (score 0):

Proper csv parsers can handle non-comma separators, assuming the fields are appropriately quoted:

```
ruby -rcsv -ne '
    row = CSV.parse_line($_, {:col_sep => " ", :quote_char => 39.chr})
    p row
' <<END
'1' 'Some+Customer Limited' 'email@somecustomerlimited.com'
END
```

```
["1", "Some+Customer Limited", "email@somecustomerlimited.com"]
```